# MDX (Mondrian): get the last month data for each year

Tags: mdx, pentaho, mondrian

I have a time dimension with an hierarchy with year->month (ano->mes as you will see below).
I've tried many examples (like this one: [MDX return last month of every year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31123785/mdx-return-last-month-of-every-year) but with no success ...

I only need to retrieve the value for the last month with data, for each year. I don't need the name of the month.

So, I came up with this:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[M1] AS 'iif([tempo.hie_d_ano_mes].currentmember = [tempo.hie_d_ano_mes].parent.lastChild, 1.0, null)' 
    MEMBER [Measures].[M2] AS '([Measures].[followers], [tempo.hie_d_ano_mes].currentmember.lastchild)'
    MEMBER [Measures].[M3] AS '(CLOSINGPERIOD([tempo.hie_d_ano_mes].[mes], [tempo.hie_d_ano_mes].CurrentMember), [Measures].[followers])' 
    SELECT CrossJoin({[hie].[Grupo UC]}, [tempo.hie_d_ano_mes].[2015] : [tempo.hie_d_ano_mes].[2016]) ON ROWS, 
    NON EMPTY {[Measures].[followers], [Measures].[M2]} ON COLUMNS 
    FROM [cubo_social]
```

But it only returns the last month value for the last year in the database (2016 in this case):
[image: Image 01]